# php how to specify table inside $row

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose the following PHP code:

```
$query="SELECT USERS.mail,EXPERTS.mail FROM USERS,EXPERTS WHERE USERS.ID<=10 AND 
EXPERTS.FK_ID=USERS.ID";            
$result=$db->query($query);        
if ($result->num_rows>=1) 
{       
  $row=$result->fetch_assoc(); 
  $data=$row["mail"];   
}
```

Column "mail" inside $row corresponds to table USERS or table EXPERTS? How may I select the desired table? I tried $data=$row["USERS.mail"]; and it did not work...

Thank you very much

Comment: update query as  $query="SELECT USERS.mail as `um`,EXPERTS.mail as `em` FROM USERS,EXPERTS WHERE USERS.ID<=10 AND 
EXPERTS.FK_ID=USERS.ID" ...and get $row['um'] and $row['em']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$query="SELECT USERS.mail as users_mail,EXPERTS.mail as experts_mail 
        FROM USERS,EXPERTS 
        WHERE USERS.ID<=10 AND EXPERTS.FK_ID=USERS.ID";            
$result=$db->query($query);        
if ($result->num_rows>=1) 
{       
  $row=$result->fetch_assoc(); 
  $data=$row["users_mail"]; 
  // or
  // $data=$row["users_mail"]; 
}
```

it uses identifiers (or aliases) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html

`table.column AS identifier`

Answer (score 3):

Use aliases in the query:

```
SELECT USERS.mail AS u_mail, EXPERTS.mail AS e_mail ...
```

Then you can access `$row['u_mail']` and `$row['e_mail']`.